# Ajax response to JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to achieve this using JavaScript.

```
[{ "employeeName":"emp1", "Deaprtment":"dept1"},
 { "employeeName":"emp2", "Deaprtment":"dept1"}
]
```

to

```
 {"dept1":{"emp1","emp2"}}
```

Please advise for possible solution using JavaScript.

Comment: You want to group by departments? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: your expected object syntax is incorrect.

Comment: The required result isn't valid. Did you mean `{"dept1":["emp1","emp2"]}`?

Comment: You will have to loop throw it and create an entire new json :-\

Comment: @JJJ +1, i think you are correct.

Comment: see here : https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/Lgxrcc5p/

Comment: "Asia": {
                   
                    "India": ["New Delhi", "Mumbai", "Bangalore", "Chennai"],
                    "Japan": ["Tokyo", "Kyoto", "Nagoya", "Hiroshima"],
                    "Singapore": ["Singapore"],
                 
                },
                "Europe": {
                
                    "UK": ["London", "Birmingham", "Liverpool", "Bristol"],
                   
                }  make this from {{"Asia":"India","Mubmai"},{Asia,Japan,Tokiyo}, etc.....}  see here https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/Lgxrcc5p/

Comment: [ { Continent:Asia, Country: India, City:New Delhi} , {Continent:Asia, Country:India, City:Mumbai},{Continent:Europe, Country:UK, City:London},{Continent:Europe,Country:UK,City:Birmingham}] need to convert into above

Answer (score 1):

Your given expected output is not valid, But you can get output like this.

```js
var arr = [{ "employeeName":"emp1", "Deaprtment":"dept1"},
 { "employeeName":"emp2", "Deaprtment":"dept1"}
];

var newObj = {};
for(let i in arr){
  if(arr[i].Deaprtment in newObj){
    newObj[arr[i].Deaprtment].push(arr[i].employeeName);
  }else{
    newObj[arr[i].Deaprtment] = [arr[i].employeeName];
  }
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking output as `{"dept1":["emp1","emp2"]}`, then use `reduce`

```
var output = arr.reduce( ( a, b ) => ( 
   a[ b.Deaprtment ] = a[ b.Deaprtment ] || [], 
   a[ b.Deaprtment ].push( b.employeeName ), 
a ) ,{} );
```